# mixing C & C++ code in static library

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a static library that contains C and C++ functions and then use this library in a C environment. As per [Using C++ library in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code/199422#199422), I wrap C functions around C++ functions.

The makefile for the library uses "ar -rvs libNAMEX.a $(OBJECTS)" where OBJECTS contains the object files compiled by gcc or g++ depending on type (GCC version 4.4.1).

I don't encounter any errors when building the library. But when I try to compile a C file (with a cross-compiled version of GCC 4.5.1) that used the library: "gcc -L[PATH TO libNAMEX.a] -lNAMEX ... c_source.c", it gives me errors related to C++ extensions (i.e., "undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)", "undefined reference to`std::allocator::~allocator()'").

Are there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use g++ as linker:

```
gcc my_c_file.c -c
g++ my_c_file.o -L blabla -lblabla
```

Comment: or add `-lstdc++` and still use gcc. If you have one, you should have the other though...