# Can c++ libraries run in c?

Tags: c

I'm sorry if this is a basic question(I'm new to c/c++, but I'm a little confused at how to get the answer.  [stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) is a c++ library but some of my code is in c.  I know c++ can use c code(my c code is embedded in c++), but does it work the other way around so c can run c++ code?

Their site only mentions c++ but I'm wondering if there's something special that can be done to run c++ libraries within c?

Sorry the books I have read talk about using c code in c++ and the c book I read was written before c++ came out. Right now my c function is sending data to my c++ code which is using the c++ library and then sending results back so I'm thinking I want to test performance if I cut the middle man(c++).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C++ library in C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code)

Comment: That book is what... two, three decades outdated now?

Comment: @K-ballo: K&R Second Edition is quite old but still the best book for learning C... age isn't everything.

Comment: @sarnold: After C++ came out, both C and C++ standards have evolved quite a bit... Remember the weird function syntax in K&R C? Aren't those outdated by now?

Comment: @K-ballo: That's why I said _Second Edition_, to get the new function syntax. :) And yes, the standards are the best place to answer complicated questions, but as a learning guide, K&R II is far and away one of the best books ever written on any subject. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to a C++ library from C only when the C++ library has been designed to be used from C. Specifically, the functions the library provides need to be exported with `extern "C" {}` block to avoid name mangling, and the interface should be designed in a way to be usable from plain C (i.e. no classes or member functions, only functionless structs and plain functions).

It is worth mentioning that you can compile your C code with a C++ compiler, and it will for the most part be OK. This lets you pretend that your C code is a C++ code, and freely mix in functionality provided through C++ - specific interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a links that may help you:
[How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

Comment: Welcome to [SO] -- please note when giving an answer that consists of just an URL, it'll often be converted to a comment instead. Please consider summarizing the content of the page, so it'll still be useful even if the page goes dark. Thanks!