# Compiling C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I have a program written in C and I need to use [KDIS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kdis/) libraries which are written in C++. I compile my C program with automake&friends in KDevelop. How can I compile everything together?? Because I want to call some KDIS functions inside my C program.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what type of interface does the library provide for you? C or C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to call C++ functions which are not declated `extern "C"`, then you have to do so from a C++ program yourself. You can create one single C++ file in your project which wraps all the library functions you need in `extern "C"` functions to be used by the rest of your project. You'll have to tell autotools that you're using both C and C++. The file extensions should be enough to decide which is which.

To give you an example, consider the following `mymagic.cc` creating bindings for some `libmagic` written in C++:

```
#include <libmagic/magic.hh>
extern "C" {
  int doMagic() {
    magic::Wizard w("foo", 42);
    magic::Result res = w.doMagic();
    return res.getResultCode();
  }
}
```

To the rest of your application, `doMagic()` would appear as just another C function. But the inside is C++, so it can use any C++ constructs you want. When you need to pass stuff from your library around, you should use pointers to opaque types. So in the header `mymagic.h` which is also used by your C code, you can write

```
struct magicValue;
int doMagic(void);
struct magicValue* createMagic(void);
void destroyMagic(struct magicValue*);
```

And in the `mymagic.cc` you'd then be more explicit:

```
struct magicValue {
    magic::value v;
    magicValue(magic::value val) : v(val) { }
};
magicValue* createMagic() {
    return new magicValue(magic::value("foo"));
}
void destroyMagic(magicValue*) {
    delete magicValue;
}
```

Comment: So I should create a main.c with extern "all functions in C++". But the parameters of that functions are C++??

Comment: @dani: If KDIS doesn't provide a C interface, then you need to invent one. It's up to you how to achieve that, but generally you will find yourself defining opaque pointer types in C to refer to the object types in C++, and writing a lot of functions of the form `ReturnType Foo_method(Foo *self, other args ...) { return self->method(other args...); }`.

Comment: @dani, I'm not sure I understand your comment. But I added some example, hope this clarifies things. Also have a look at the links SingerOfTheFall [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11755623/1468366), they appear to have a lot more detail on how to not only call functions but pass data in various ways between C and C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop, feel free to edit the answer and include your example if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#cpp_from_c) may help you understand how to mix C and C++ code in your application.

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code) Stack Overflow question, I believe that's what you need.

Comment: This answer, in my opinion, is more appropriate as a comment than as an answer.