# Minimal set of C++ features reusable in a C project that lead to (almost?) zero glue code

Tags: c++, c

*Disclaimer*: I know purists on either side, C or C++, will not like this. The job needs to get done.

I would like to use as many non-OOP related features of C++ to make my C-like coding (but compiled with a C++ compiler, of course) more enjoyable. The end product should be a C-like library (and an accompanying executable) which is relatively easy to embed in C programs.

What I would terribly need is **function overloading**, for instance. I guess the client code (written in C) could use **libffi** or similar to get the mangled named, so the functions can be called.

Other nice features would be **default values** and perhaps **templates**.

I wouldn't use any C++ library (only C), no exceptions, no RTTI, and no objects.

1. *What is the complete list of C++ features which are not in C, which I could use under these restrictions, and what are some common libraries and techniques to make it work as painlessly as possible?*
2. *What should I pay attention to?*

I know about the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code), but as I've said, I don't want **any glue code** (perhaps with the exception of the mangling part, which the client would have to do if he doesn't use C++), and I wouldn't use any OOP features. I am ready to make compromises.

Comment: I didn't know there was such thing as a C purist anymore.

Comment: @Aesthete There's bunch of them on IRC: #C @ freenode

Comment: I don't see any conceptual difference between your question and the related question. The so-called "glue code" is just an `#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {` in the files that export functions.

Comment: @Aesthete depends on what your definition of "purist" is. By the time you get to the latest C standards you've pretty-much sold your soul to the C++ wench anyway.

Comment: @Alex But can polymorphism be used inside an `extern "C"` block?

Comment: Polymorphism is an OOP feature, isn't it?

Comment: @hate-engine within this discussion, "polymorphic" is restricted to functions. You know, "one function name, different signatures, same purpose".

Comment: @Flavius, what do you mean as "function polymorphism"? Function overloading? It's not supported in C.

Comment: Sounds like it would be neither fish nor fowl.

Comment: @hate-engine yes. I've fixed my question. I know it's not supported in C.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is, you end up using C++ anyway because you're going to use a C++ compiler? You even explicitly say you want to use templates/overloading, knowing they're not C. If you want to do procedural programming in C++, go ahead, but the only one putting in restrictions is yourself, there is no absolute guideline here. If you want to export a C-library without glue code, bad luck: use C for that.

Comment: Isn't your question really about how to link a C++ library to a C module?

Comment: @Kenneth yes, but how to write the C++ library such that there's no need for glue code in the C++ library, but only a thin layer in the client code (the "C module").

Comment: @KillianDS I know what I end up doing. I clearly said `C-like`, not `C`. Read my question.

Comment: @KillianDS I know there is no formal definition of "C-like", that's why I've clearly described what that means in my question. Read the question, please.

Comment: @Flavius See KillianDS' comment. You can't. Best bet would be to compile your C code with a C++ compiler and link it with your lib.

Comment: @Kenneth Not even if I write the C++ code procedural style with function overloading & co, and tell the client that if he wants to call the library from C code, he has to use some sort of `ffi` to get the mangled names and find the pointers to the functions in my C++ library?

Comment: @Flavius I believe the FFI that exists between C++ and C is the extern "C" decleration which _disables_ function overloading to make the function callable from C hence defeating your purpose. C++ promises to be 99% compatible with C, so it is a lot safer to program procedurally in C++ with the extra features you like and just be done with it. Even if you could force C to use C++ features it puts all the responsibility for type handling and error checking on your _client_, which is not what you usually want to worry about when using a library.

Comment: @Kenneth the whole point of writing procedural code in C++ was embeddability in C. Are there any other POSSIBLE advantages in writing it procedurally?

Comment: @Flavius That is always a design question. If it makes sense to write it procedurally, do so. If it makes sense to implement an inheritance hierarchy by all means do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get downvoted a lot for this, because this doesn't really answer the question, but...

- If you want to be called portably from the outside, use C prototypes. No overloading, no default arguments, no templates, no C++ types. Only C types, ie. integers, floating point numbers and pointers (pointers to opaque incomplete C++ structures are OK). Requiring a client library to use libffi or similar is asking for trouble.
- If you want to use C++ features and libraries, you can use them and still comply with the above with a little work (don't forget `extern "C"`, and catch all exceptions).

If the client is not willing to use C++ (which is perfectly understandable), you'll have to write glue code anyway. The only solution to minimize glue code is to design a *clean API*.

It is possible to write the "top layer" (close to the externally visible API) in a way that will require almost no glue, and use C++ for the internals.