# C++ exception handling in C codes

Tags: c++, c, exception

When we write a program in C, it is possible that we will call some libraries that were wrote in C++ but had a C interface. Then it may happen that when we call these libraries, a C++ exception will occur. So my question is how we can handle this situation. I am more interested in this problem from a C++ developer's perspective. Suppose I am developing a C++ library that will be invoked by a C program, should I stop using exception and instead return error codes? Another situation is that if I have already a fully developed C++ library that uses exception, how can I transfer this library in a quick way that will only use error returning method?

Comment: That is no duplicate because it doesn't answer the question what to do with exceptions. There's just one answer saying "beware of exceptions" without any solution provided.

Comment: @Lundin, I don't think there is a universal solution here. The possible ones would be to rewrite the code without using exceptions at all, or to make wrappers in such a way that the exceptions do not leave the library's own code, I suppose?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I don't know either, I would probably hack up some wrapper thing like that myself. But I'm curious to know if there's some recommended practice or perhaps some C++ language feature that is useful. And since that other question wasn't helpful in providing answers for that, please don't close this one.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code this link will be helpful, thanks

Comment: Neither the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code) nor the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/199422/1600898) mention exceptions at all. How is this a duplicate?

Comment: You shouldn't allow exceptions to propagate across module boundaries anyway, even when all modules are written in C++ (cf. C++ Coding Standards #62 by Sutter & Alexandrescu. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to catch all exceptions on the C++ side and convert them to appropriate error returns in C, which may include specific error codes where appropriate. This doesn't mean that you stop using exceptions — you can still use them in C++ — but you can't expose them to C, they become an implementation detail.

A typical wrapper can be structured as follows:

```
// thingy-wrapper.h, typically included from C code:

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// create a typedef visible to C that doesn't expose the layout of
// the implementation.
typedef void *thingy_t;

// wrapper for std::string Thingy::get_name()
char *thingy_get_name(thingy_t t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// thingy-wrapper.cpp, implements the wrapper, compiled with C++:

#include <thingy-wrapper.h>
#include <thingy.hpp>         // declares Thingy class

char *thingy_get_name(thingy_t t_)
{
  try {
    Thingy& t = *static_cast<Thingy*>(t_);
    std::string name = t.get_name();
    return strdup(name.c_str());
  }
  catch(...) {
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

In this simple example, the caller of `thingy_get_name` can detect that an error occurred, but cannot find out the details of the error. A more realistic example would catch specific exceptions, and set a `last_error` variable to an error code or message before returning NULL. `...` would only be caught as a last resort, and would set `last_error` to a generic `UNKNOWN_ERROR` value. A separate API for querying the last error, such as `thingy_last_error()`, would be available for the more careful callers of `thingy_get_name()`.

The separation between error and non-error results enables code that doesn't care about the cause of errors to simply check if it received `NULL`, while allowing more conscientious code to properly propagate or report the error. If your library is multi-threaded, make sure that `last_error` uses thread-local storage.

Answer (score 4):

> Then it may happen that when we call these libraries, a C++ exception will occur. So my question is how we can handle this situation.

The C code cannot handle this situation. C code cannot deal with C++ exceptions.

> Suppose I am developing a C++ library that will be invoked by a C program, should I stop using exception and instead return error codes?

No. If you want the C++ library to be consumed by C++ code you should use native C++ error handling. Which means exceptions.

However, the interface that you expose to the C code must not throw exceptions. Typically this means writing an adaptor layer that catches exceptions raised by the C++ library, and converts them into error codes to be consumed by the C code.

> Another situation is that if I have already a fully developed C++ library that uses exception, how can I transfer this library in a quick way that will only use error returning method?

There's really no shortcut here. You have to write the adaptor that converts C++ exceptions into C error codes. You'll be writing an adaptor anyway if you want the library to expose interfaces for both C and C++ consumers. So the aspect of error handling is just another thing to take care of with this adaptor.

Answer (score 1):

Exception are not caught in C so if you want to catch them then in your C code or your C++ code you have to write the wrappers very carefully.

Also make sure that in your C++ functions you have your functions declared as:

```
extern "C"
```

You may also check [How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)