# Including c++ libraries in C

Tags: c++, c, boost, include

I have got a header file that includes boost libraries and I need to include this header file in a source code written in C. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to implement a wrapper around your C++ library in order to present a C API that you can call from your C code.

Comment: @zuubs You can be pretty sure that Paul R. understood that, he's not wrong. You need to wrap it.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't generally include C++ headers in a C program. You'll need to separate out the declarations that C programs might use into a separate header, and make sure these have the correct language linkage in C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// C-compatible declarations here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: How can I wrap inclusions such as #include <boost/asio.hpp> ?

Comment: @zubs: Define incomplete types for the C++ classes (Concrete classes of compatible layout for advanced uses), and declare a forwarder in the header for each C++ method you need to call. Those need to be implemented in C++ of course.

Comment: @zuubs: Just follow the duplicate link.

Comment: @zuubs: You don't. You design a C-compatible API for your library, and declare that in the C header. Only include Boost and other C++-only headers from C++ source files.

Answer (score 0):

Use adapter pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)
this post already discusses simmilar issue: [Using C++ library in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code))

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library in `C`.

But You can find many altternative of it like [GLIB](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) and [APR](http://apr.apache.org/).

Comment: I think your URL for boost is broken. I need boost for Cassandra's C++ driver https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver and there is no other way to use something else.

Comment: @zubs Check again updated it. Also boost is a collection of `C++` libraries that help you avoid writing custom code to solve common problems.And you can't modified it.