# How to configure Eclipse C project to accept C++ includes

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I have a C project in which I would like to use some C++ files.
I've modified the Makefile accordingly, but I get the

```
make\mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** No rule to make target
```

error.

I noticed that the included headers from the cpp standard library are not found.

[Headers Not Found . picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/et1v9.png)

[Edit] As a note, all the .c, .cpp, .h files are in the same folder.

If I add

```
#include <string>
```

in the .c file it is found. In the .cpp it's not.

In Eclipse I've seen that I can't set includes for C++.

[No C++ Includes . picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGcHu.png)

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you not making an C++ project?
If this is no option you have to include the path where the C++ headers are as include path to the project.

Comment: I can't make a C++ project as the main project is based on a C template and the C++ files are the source and header files from an external library (alglib)

Comment: You  probably *will* have to use a C++ `main()` function to get the C++ runtime set up properly. See [Using C++ library in C code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code)

Comment: As a first step I would like to see the includes resolved. The next one would be to actually use the C++ code in C code. (btw @BoPersson - Thank you for the link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't find any solution for this issue.
Still I am on the right path as there is a way to use the C code from Alglib.

http://forum.alglib.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3766

> It may be better to download CPython version of ALGLIB and to work with source of its computational core. It is written in C, without even trace amounts of C++, so you may find it more convenient than making wrappers around C++ core.