# how to include C++ library and header in vanilla C code

Tags: c, gcc, c++17, g++

I am trying to call C++ library (on Bessel functions) inside C code. However, I am not sure how to include `cmath` into `math.h`. Most examples are on how to include C code into C++, but I am trying to do the reverse. Here is the C++ code that appears to work:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    // spot check for nu == 0
    const double x = 1.2345;
    std::cout << "I_0(" << x << ") = " << std::cyl_bessel_i(0, x) << '\n';
 
    // series expansion for I_0
    double fct = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; fct *= ++k)
    {
        sum += std::pow(x / 2, 2 * k) / std::pow(fct, 2);
        std::cout << "sum = " << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```

How do I do this in (pure) C?

Comment: What is "vanilla C code"? If you write C you can `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: You might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199418/using-c-library-in-c-code).

Comment: @BigBoronto, I have looked at that answer, and it seems to define as `extern C` and use it in C code, however, I want the code to be in C, but the library is in C++.

Comment: MS Visual C has [Bessel functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/bessel-functions-j0-j1-jn-y0-y1-yn?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @WeatherVane, how does one use MS Visual C library with gcc?

Comment: Can you use the [GNU C library](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_19.html)?

Comment: I would argue that if you include C++ library in C, it is no longer "vanilla C". In particular, the `main` function _has to_ be compiled with C++ compiler.

Comment: @user3236841 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks! where is the source code for cyl_bessel_i?

Comment: @user3236841 Inside the standard library of each implementation. g++, clang++, MSVC, icx etc. It may be implemented as normal code (which you can read in the header files mentioned) - or it's implemented using compiler built-in functions in which case you need to read the source code for the compiler. g++ and clang++ are open source but the code is often pretty hard to read.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, thanks very much for these details!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to call C++ library (on Bessel functions) inside C code.

Generally speaking, you cannot call C++ standard library functions directly from C code unless they are also C standard library functions.  Others, typically are not C functions at all.  [`std::cyl_bessel_i()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/cyl_bessel_i) in particular, being overloaded, cannot itself be available as a C function.

> I am not sure how to include `cmath` into `math.h`.  The latter already declares all the C functions in the standard math library.  The former is the C++ version of the latter, with C++-specific additions.

In practice, you might be able to make it work for your particular C and C++ implementations by figuring out details of name mangling and explicitly linking the C++ standard library to your C program. But a safer, easier, and more portable way to do it would be to write a thin wrapper with C linkage.  Something like this:

**cyl_bessel_wrap.cpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include "cyl_bessel_wrap.h"

extern "C" double cyl_bessel_i(double nu, double x) {
    return std::cyl_bessel_i(nu, x);
}
```

**cyl_bessel_wrap.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
double cyl_bessel_i(double nu, double x);
```

Your **main.c** then looks like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cyl_bessel_wrap.h"
 
int main() {
    // spot check for nu == 0
    const double x = 1.2345;
    printf("I_0(%f) = %f\n", x, cyl_bessel_i(0, x));
 
    // series expansion for I_0
    double fct = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; fct *= ++k) {
        sum += pow(x / 2, 2 * k) / (fct * fct);
        printf("sum = %f\n", sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: do not use `pow()` (or `std::pow()`) to compute small integer powers. Especially do not use it for computing squares.  I just couldn't bring myself to leave your `std::pow(fct, 2)` as a call to `pow`.

Comment: Excellent point, perhaps the better way to do it in the above loop is to keep theprevious `pow(x/2, 2*k)` from the previous iteration and then multiply by `x/2 * x/2` and then store the updated power in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do this in (pure) C?

Reimplement all the function in C or copy or use existing C code and then use them.

There is no magic bullet. You have to *write* C code to have C code.

> how to include cmath into math.h

It is impossible to include cmath in math.h .

> how to include C++ library and header in vanilla C code

It is not possible to include C++ header in C.

It is possible to write a C wrapper around C++ library and include that C wrapper header in C code. In such case, the `main()` function *has to* be compiled with C++, making it no longer "vanilla" C.

> where can I find the C++ code (inside cmath) that does the calculation?

That depends on the specific implementation of C++ library. The algorithm in GNU libstdc++ seems to be here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/f22a7ae8a96f7e5e330b12bd5045424619aa4926/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/modified_bessel_func.tcc#L269 .